# Azure Logic App - Get Response Body with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: httpresponse, azure-logic-apps, http-response-codes, httpresponsemessage

Is there any way to get the response body in Azure Logic App even when we get 500 Internal Server Error?
I have made the Logic App in a way that I'm setting the response code to 500 on an issue, and I'm adding some error related information in the response body. I tried returning 504 Gateway timeout as well, in case of a timeout issue I could face, but I'm always receiving a null response body in case of non-200 response codes.
If we are not able to see the response body in case of an error by design, is there a better way to set and fetch error related information from the response object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get the response body in Azure Logic App by adding the response action. According to this [Add a Response action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-a-response-action) section of the Microsoft document.

> When you use the Request trigger to handle inbound requests, you can model the response and send the payload results back to the caller by using the built-in Response action.

Following steps would help you to get the response body.

- In the Logic App Designer, under the step where you want to add a Response action, select **New step**.
- The under **Choose an action**, in the search box, enter `response` as your filter, and select the **Response** action.
- Now add any values that are required for the response message. For the **Body**, you can select the trigger body output from the dynamic content list.

[image: responseAction]

I would suggest to read the [Receive and respond to inbound HTTPS requests in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-a-response-action) document for more information.

Alternatively you can also create alerts whenever HTTP 500 errors occur in your App and use Application Insights to view it using [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling#set-up-azure-monitor-logs). I would also suggest to read this [Handle errors and exceptions in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling#catch-and-handle-failures-by-changing-run-after-behavior) Microsoft document for more information.

Comment: Setting the body manually in case of a 500 error helped receive the body in case of error response too.