# Azure functions Response Body is missing in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

[image]I am processing data from Event Hub. Whenever events are available in event hub series of azure functions are called sequentially to processes the data.

function A is using event data as input  --> function B is using output of function A as an input and likewise 2 more functions are there.

Response body is missing in only one function (**same,** ex.: function B in picture)  in some iterations.

Sometimes response body for one of the azure function is missing however response code is 200. I have logged the response body in azure function before returning the response and it(response body) is present in logs.

What can be the reason of not getting the response body.

In the attached image Function B is having this issue.

**Update:** After adding concurrency control to 1(*So that it runs sequentially*) issue is resolved however again after removing concurrency control issue is coming. What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue,

*Make sure that all of the azure function has been created in the same region that might be the reason for not getting the request body for one function and getting for others*.

*Would suggest you to create Azure logic app and functions in the same region.*

***Another workaround is to provide the content type in your event hub to `application/json` if still having the same the try to set text/plain.***

[image]

*For more information please refer this* **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***Receive and respond to inbound HTTPS requests in Azure Logic Apps***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-a-response-action)

*For the similar issue please refer this* **MS Q&A**| [***Http Webhook Outputs does not have body content, only headers***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/45800/http-webhook-outputs-does-not-have-body-content-on.html) .

Comment: 1. I am using application/json.
2. Function app and logic app both are in same region.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Could you please let us know have you specified request body inside foreach loop. Also please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158398/azure-logic-app-get-response-body-with-500-internal-server-error) regarding to get the response body

Comment: Yes, I am passing CURRENT_ITEM to the function inside foreach loop.